# How to get sum of Column cells with the same value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the sum quantity of product with the same Id added to my table using jquery. for example i have a table with a product(Bread) added multiple times among other product i want to get the total quantity of bread added to the cart list. so i intend to use the prodduct ID to find it via the foreach loop  this is the code i tried

```
    function FindSumOfQuantityWIthSameID() {
    var ProductId = $("#item").val();
    var NewQuantity = parseFloat($("#txtQuantity").val());
    var SumQuantity = 0;
    var Total = 0;
    $("#cartList").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        Total = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").has(ProductId).val().text());
        SumQuantity += Total;
    });
    var FTD = SumQuantity + NewQuantity;
    alert(FTD);
}
```

heres my Html Table

```
<table class="table" id="cartList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th hidden>
                        Item Id
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">
                        Product
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">
                        Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">
                        SN/IMEI
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">
                        Total
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">
                        Remove
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
        </table>
```

The Jquery populated table body

```
 var ItemList = "<tr><td hidden>" +
        ProductId +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        ItemName +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        parseFloat(Amount).toFixed(2) +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        Quantity +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        Description +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        SN_IMEI +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align: center'>" +
        parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2) +
        "</td><td class='border-0 align-middle' style='text-align:center'><a name='remove' class='text-danger' onclick='Removeitem(this)'><i class='icon ni ni-trash'></i></a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you add also an example of your html table.

Comment: Thanks i just did

Comment: Another question: Do you mean you want get the sum of same table cells or same values in any cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your each loop you can check if the first `td` has the value equal to `productId` if yes get that value and add in *total* else just consider value has 0 .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
FindSumOfQuantityWIthSameID();

function FindSumOfQuantityWIthSameID() {
  var ProductId = 1; //just for demo
  var NewQuantity = 2; //just from demo..
  var SumQuantity = 0;
  var Total = 0;
  $("#cartList").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function() {
    //check if the first td which has id matchs product id
    Total = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim()) == ProductId ? parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text()) : 0;
    SumQuantity += Total;
  });
  var FTD = SumQuantity + NewQuantity;
  console.log(FTD);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="cartList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th hidden>
        Item Id
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:center">
        Product
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:center">
        Price
      </th>
      <th style="text-align: center">
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th style="text-align: center">
        Description
      </th>
      <th style="text-align: center">
        SN/IMEI
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:center">
        Total
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:center">
        Remove
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td hidden="">1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethings1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">123.3</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">12</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethins ...</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">ab2d</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">100</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align:center"><a name="remove" class="text-danger" onclick="Removeitem(this)">x<i class="icon ni ni-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td hidden="">2</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethings2</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">123.33</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethins ...</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">abd</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">100</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align:center"><a name="remove" class="text-danger" onclick="Removeitem(this)">x<i class="icon ni ni-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td hidden="">1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethings1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">123.33</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">1</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">somethins ...</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">abd</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align: center">100</td>
      <td class="border-0 align-middle" style="text-align:center"><a name="remove" class="text-danger" onclick="Removeitem(this)">x<i class="icon ni ni-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```